# The maximum number of bytes allowed to be read from the stream has > been exceeded

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to create a list item through REST api, but the multitext field contains content larger than 1mb and I'm getting this error:

> "The maximum number of bytes allowed to be read from the stream has
>   been exceeded. After the last read operation, a total of 1049600 bytes
>   has been read from the stream; however a maximum of 1048576 bytes is
>   allowed."

Any way to address / bypass this in O365

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: sorry dont remember

Comment: any updates, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the batch size, like I was using 1000 records to insert in batch, I reduced it to 200 threshold and it is working, got 200 by hit and trial.